# How to get the 10 highest values for each group in a data frame?

Tags: r, sorting, aggregate

I am assuming this is an easy thing but I am unable to solve my problem.

I have a data frame with 9 columns and I want to get the highest 3 values of the 4th column (LumenLenght) sorted for each group given in the first column.

I would like to be able to: 
a) find the 10 rows with the highest values for column 4 separated for each  SampleID (first column) 
b) average the 10 values for each SampleID

[image: data frame]

My current code a) sorts first the values according to SampleID and LumenLength and b) separates the highest, second highest and third highest LumenLength value per SampleID.

```
sorted.v= arrange(sorted.v, desc(SampleId), LumenLength)
maxlength1 = aggregate(sorted.v$LumenLength,by = list(sorted.v$SampleId),  FUN = tail, n = 1)#highest value
maxlength2 = aggregate(sorted.v$LumenLength,by = list(sorted.v$SampleId),  FUN = tail, n = 2)#second highest value
maxlength3 = aggregate(sorted.v$LumenLength,by = list(sorted.v$SampleId),  FUN = tail, n = 3)#3. highest value
```

As you can see, I haven't really reached my goal jet.
I am also pretty sure there is a better way of doing it but I  stuck right now.

Comment: In your description, it was mentioned earlier that you need the top 3, then it changed to top 10, and mean of that.  What is the expected output?  Also, please don't show dataset as an image.  Instead use `dput`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `top_n` from `dplyr` even without `arrange` ing the dataset.

```
sorted.v %>%
    group_by(SampleId) %>%
    top_n(10, LumenLength) %>%
    summmarise(MeanLumenArea = mean(LumenLength))
```

Comment: Uhh awesome! Thanks a lot

Comment: I checked the data just now. And sometimes, when the 10 biggest LumenLength are unequall to the biggest 10 LumenArea data, the result will be more than 10 values. 
If I try the following i always get only 10 values back. But When I use LumenLength, Lumen Width etc the results are quite variable and seem to be mainly sorted by LumenArea....:sorted.v %>%
    group_by(SampleId) %>%
    top_n(10, LumenLength) %>%
    summarise(MeanLumenArea = mean(LumenArea))

Comment: @Carola Can you update your post with a reproducible example with expected output so that I can check it. (please use `dput`)